# Using multiple fonts in one Json skin

Tags: java, json, libgdx, bitmap-fonts

I am using one skin for my menu, and I am wondering if it is possible to add several fonts to this skin and then pick which font to use programatically.

Currently I set a font and add it to the LabelStyle like this:

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
        "fontTest": { "file": "outline_test.fnt" }
    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
        "default": {
            "font": "fontTest", "fontColor": "white"
        }
    },
```

Which mean that when I create a Label all I need to do to get this font is:

```
Label rating = new Label("Rating: ", skin);
```

This picks the LabelStyle that is set as default, is there any way to reference the LabelStyles set in my Json-file so that I can pick which style to use in my Java-code? Or do I need to create a seperate skin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can add several font styles in Skin file

Let' say you want to create a Label Style called "myStyleFontTest" and it uses a different font

```
"com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont": {
        "fontTest": { "file": "outline_test.fnt" },
        "myStyleFontTest": { "file": "myStyle.fnt" }
    },

    "com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle": {
        "default": {
            "font": "fontTest", "fontColor": "white"
        },
        "myLabelStyle" :  {
            "font": "myStyleFontTest", "fontColor": "red"
        }
    },
```

Now when you create a new label, all you have to do is

```
Label testLabel = new Label(text, skin, "myLabelStyle")
```

Comment: I think maybe you mixed it up a bit and put the Style under BitmapFonts?

Comment: It's fine, got what you meant :) Works fine, thanks!